# How to "timeout" a function so that it only runs once every 5 seconds eventhough it is called multiple times per second

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, notification, sed

See below:

```
still_notify=false
has_been_notified=false
notify()
{
        $has_been_notified && return
        watching=$(if [[ $(GET http://$ipplexserver:32400/status/sessions?X-Plex-Token=$plexapitoken | grep -o "^</Video>$") ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi)
        if [[ $watching = false ]]
        then
                clear
                echo "Updating notification"
                echo "--------------------------------"
                echo "Nobody is watching media on your plex server anymore"
                echo "You can now update plex"
                echo "-----"
                echo "You see this message because you chose to be notified when you were trying to update plex"
                echo "--------------------------------"
                sed -i "s|^still_notify=true$|still_notify=false|" $filelocation/advancedplexapi.sh
                read -rp "continue | update: " notifyoption
                if [[ ${notifyoption,,} = "continue" ]]
                then
                        echo "this is to exit out of the if statement" >> /dev/null

                elif [[ ${notifyoption,,} = update ]]
                then
                        option=update
                fi
                has_been_notified=true
        fi
}

if [[ $still_notify = true ]]
then
        trap notify DEBUG
fi

if [[ if-statement ]]
then
       sed -i "s|^still_notify=false$|still_notify=true|" $filelocation/advancedplexapi.sh
       trap notify DEBUG
fi
```

This is a notification system inside my script. When the bottom if-statement is run the script continues but in the background, it checks the plex api and if the if-statement is true, it shows a message. It checks the api (see watching variable) everytime a commands is executed in the script (due to DEBUG being used in the trap command). My script is so big (2800 lines) that it runs the notify function multiple times per second (sometimes 10x per second). This makes my script incredibly slow (due to the amount of api requests), sometimes even unusable, and the function doesn't even have to run that many times.

I want to have it so that once the function is run, it can't be run for the next 5 seconds, no matter how many times it is being called by the trap command. Like a sleep/timeout for the function. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
timeout=false
still_notify=false
has_been_notified=false
notify()
{
        if [[ $timeout = false ]]
        then
        sed -i "s|^timeout=false$|timeout=true|" $filelocation/advancedplexapi.sh
        $has_been_notified && return
        watching=$(if [[ $(GET http://$ipplexserver:32400/status/sessions?X-Plex-Token=$plexapitoken | grep -o "^</Video>$") ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi)
        if [[ $watching = false ]]
        then
                clear
                echo "Updating notification"
                echo "--------------------------------"
                echo "Nobody is watching media on your plex server anymore"
                echo "You can now update plex"
                echo "-----"
                echo "You see this message because you chose to be notified when you were trying to update plex"
                echo "--------------------------------"
                sed -i "s|^still_notify=true$|still_notify=false|" $filelocation/advancedplexapi.sh
                read -rp "continue | update: " notifyoption
                if [[ ${notifyoption,,} = "continue" ]]
                then
                        echo "this is to exit out of the if statement" >> /dev/null

                elif [[ ${notifyoption,,} = update ]]
                then
                        option=update
                fi
                has_been_notified=true
        fi
}

while true
do
        sleep 5s
        sed -i "s|^timeout=true$|timeout=false|" $filelocation/advancedplexapi.sh
done &

if [[ $still_notify = true ]]
then
        trap notify DEBUG
fi

if [[ if-statement ]]
then
       sed -i "s|^still_notify=false$|still_notify=true|" $filelocation/advancedplexapi.sh
       trap notify DEBUG
fi
```

Comment: Can't you intervene at the level of the trap command, i.e., check time there and only make the call to the function when a minimum time has passed?

Comment: I thought of that too. The problem is that the message only correctly shows when using trap. I previously had a loop with `sleep 5s` and `notify` run in the background, but that didn't properly work. The way it does now with the trap command does. So I'm trying to keep using the trap command. I'm searching for a `DEBUG BUT ONLY EVERY FIVE SECONDS` instead of `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an intermediate function to keep track of the time. If rlimit is older than a second, re-set epoch to the rlimit variable in the global scope.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

debug_func(){
    local -n a=rlimit
    ((($EPOCHSECONDS - a) > 1)) && \
        { a=$EPOCHSECONDS; notify; }
}
trap debug_func DEBUG

notify(){
    echo "Ding Dong!"
}

echo  1..
echo  2..
echo  3..
sleep 2
echo  4..
```